# How to make custom combobox inside ASPxGridView

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

Is it possible to have combobox with 2 valuefields, other words, if we are inserting some columns, this combobox should give value to 2 columns. Hope its undersentable.

Is it possible to have combobox like this inside ASPxGridView?

Comment: You can concatenate the values and insert in comboBox.

Comment: @Murtaza: its not problem to bind data, I have table with 3 rows, id and 2 values, that should be binded and used for filling 2 values on inserting in other table, I just cant manage to make it work.

Comment: Please explain properly 3 rows or 3 columns.. and what does this statement mean "used for filling 2 values on inserting in other table".

Comment: Table that should be binded to that combobox have 3 columns: unique id, time 1, and time 2. On other place in gridview I have several columns, and 2 of them should be filled from combobox binded to mentioned table. So on inserting, 2 values/columns should be filled from selected row of combobox. Hope its more clear now. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this procedure:
1. Submit one combo box value
2. In [ASPxGridView.RowInserting](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridViewASPxGridView_RowInsertingtopic) event use that value (retrieve it from e.NewValues) to fetch others.
3. Insert fetched values into e.NewValues.

This will work if you can fetch all row values using combo box value.